# No SoundCards found probably permission problem

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

The output of `aplay -l` is: no soundcards found, but when I do `sudo aplay -l` I get:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtrt5650 [chtrt5650], device 0: 1 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I thought this is a permission problem so tried to add my user (mohamed) to audio group using: `sudo adduser mohamed audio`, But didn't work.
I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, if not how can I add the user to the group? if it's right what could be the problem?

note: I followed the instructions in [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) to update the ALSA drivers but didn't affect anything

EDIT: output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root         80 Jul 25 16:53 by-path
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116, 10 Jul 25 16:53 comprC1D1
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  2 Jul 25 16:53 controlC0
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  7 Jul 25 16:53 controlC1
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  6 Jul 25 16:53 hwC0D2
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  3 Jul 25 16:53 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  4 Jul 25 16:53 pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  5 Jul 25 16:53 pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  9 Jul 25 16:53 pcmC1D0c
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  8 Jul 25 16:53 pcmC1D0p
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116,  1 Jul 25 16:53 seq
crw-rw----. 1 root hwaudio 116, 33 Jul 25 16:53 timer
```

output of `ps -ef | grep pulse`:

```
mohamed  11954  1321  0 17:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
mohamed  13946 13576  0 17:34 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulse
```

I can see my user ID in the audio group using: `grep audio /etc/group`

```
audio:x:600:pulse,mohamed
hwaudio:x:18:
```

I'm using crouton on my chromebook if that anyhow important.

Comment: What are the permissions set on the audio devices? (See the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`.) And does `id mohamed` list the audio group? (You probably have to log in again.)

Comment: @CL. the output is ```total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       80 Jul 25 15:42 by-path
crw-rw----. 1 root audio 116, 10 Jul 25 15:42 comprC1D1
crw-rw----. 1 root audio 116,  2 Jul 25 15:42 controlC0
crw-rw----. 1 root audio 116,  7 Jul 25 15:42 controlC1
crw-rw----. 1 root audio 116,  6 Jul 25 15:42 hwC0D2
crw-rw----. 1 root audio 116,  3 Jul 25 15:42 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----. 1 root audio 116,  4 Jul 25 15:42 pcmC0D7p```
it's a bit longer, and the the user ID is not there. What do you mean log in again? I logged out and in again but no good.

Comment: It seems the files did not get extended acl attributes.  `ps -ef | grep pulse` please these output in your question. You can edit it.

Comment: To be sure: you'll need to login again, after joining a group. Type 'id' (without '') in any terminal to see if 'audio' is already set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a user to a group, use:

```
usermod -a -G hwaudio mohamed
```

Comment: I did that but didn't work, still getting no soundcards found

Comment: Then add to `hwaudio`.

Comment: This solved the problem on Linux, but another problem persist which is when I start linux (virtual machine) the audio won't work on chrome os, unless I turn linux off again. Any idea why?